# roxygen2/ how to have only one help page for S4 generic and its methods?

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

Despite of experimenting with various stackoverflow answers on the topic and reading support documentation: 
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html

I still haven't been able to create a package help page that would contain an S4 generic function and all of its methods as one and only one help page.

```
#' generic function for plotting classical multidimensional scaling
#' @param object (ReportClass or RunClass)
#' @rdname plotCMDS
#' @export

setGeneric("plotCMDS", function(object) {
standardGeneric("plotCMDS")})

#' @rdname plotCMDS
#' @export
setMethod("plotCMDS", signature(object = "ReportClass"), function(object) {
object@cdms})

#' @rdname plotCMDS
#' @export
setMethod("plotCMDS", signature(object = "RunClass"), function(object) {
listcmds <- lapply(object@reports, function(x) slot(x, "cmds"))
listcmds <- lapply(listcmds, `[[`, 1)
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange,  listcmds)})
```

This still shows in RStudio as two separate help pages both having the same
content:
[image]

I would like to have only one help page:"plotCMDS generic function for plotting classical multidimensional scaling" including both the generic and its two methods.

Comment: An alternative to \@describeIn is \@rdname. It overrides the default file name generated by roxygen and merges documentation for multiple objects into one file. This gives you the complete freedom to combine documentation as you see fit. from: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#text-formatting, just scratching my head over similar stuff. Hope this helps. The escapes were just to indicate that rdname is not an SOF user name

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The help pages were correcty rendered in the pdf file as specified above. It was just that pdf file and RStudio GUI rendered the help pages differently.